# merge two matrix and its attributes in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I've two matrix a and b and I'd like to combine the rows in a way that in the first row I got no duplicate value and in the second value, columns in a & b which have the same row value get added together in new matrix. i.e.

```
a =
 1     2     3
 8     2     5

b =
 1     2     5     7
 2     4     6     1
```

Desired outputc =

```
 1     2     3     5     7
10     6     5     6     1
```

Any help is welcomed,please.

Comment: What do you mean by combine/merge? What happens if the input matrices have different rows/columns size?

Comment: as in the example, columns are of arbitrary size. the first row is as the key and I'd like to have non-duplicate value of this row (e.g. by union(a(1,:)),b(1,:)). for the other rows, whatever they have equal first row value, these get added together (e.g. 8 from a and 2 from b are added and result is 10 for the value beneath 1 in the output matrix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For two-row matrices

You want to add second-row values corresponding to the same first-row value. This is a typical use of [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[ii, ~, kk] = unique([a(1,:) b(1,:)]);
result = [ ii; accumarray(kk(:), [a(2,:) b(2,:)].').'];
```

### General case

If you need to accumulate columns with an arbitrary number of columns (based on the first-row value), you can use [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) as follows:

```
[ii, ~, kk] = unique([a(1,:) b(1,:)]);
r = repmat((1:size(a,1)-1).', 1, numel(kk));
c = repmat(kk.', size(a,1)-1, 1);
result = [ii; full(sparse(r,c,[a(2:end,:) b(2:end,:)]))];
```

Comment: exactly! I got the meaning of accumarray finally:). will you explain a bit what is ~ and your second line script?

Comment: @hamideh `~` just means "ignore that output". It's like `[ii, jj, kk] = unique([a(1,:) b(1,:)]);` but you don't need `jj`

Comment: @hamideh For the second line, I suggest you observe `kk(:)`, then `[a(2,:) b(2,:)].'` and then `accumarray(kk(:), [a(2,:) b(2,:)].')`. That will make ot obvious what's going on: `accumarray` sums the second-input values corresponding to the same first-input value

Comment: Thanks,what happens if we have cells. Is it extendable for cellarray too?

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway, if you _need_ cell arrays that's because sizes don't match (for example some column of `a` has more rows than the others), and in that case you can't even _define_ the sum. If by cell arrays you simply mean `a = {1 2 3; 8 2 5};` then the first step would be `a = cell2mat(a);` to convert into a matrix

Comment: Is there any similar way for finding the max of two matrix? I mean having unique ids in first row and whenever there are different attributes related to unique ids in other rows, find the max of them. any help is so welcomed!

Comment: For _two-row matrices_: yes, the `accumarray`-based approach is easily modified to handle max: `[ii, ~, kk] = unique([a(1,:) b(1,:)]); result = [ ii; accumarray(kk(:), [a(2,:) b(2,:)].', [], @max).']`